# How do I filter the choices in a ModelForm that has a CharField with the choices attribute (and hence a Select Field)

Tags: python, django

I understand I am able to filter queryset of Foreignkey or Many2ManyFields, however, how do I do that for a simple CharField that is a Select Widget (Select Tag).

For example:

```
PRODUCT_STATUS = (
                  ("unapproved", "Unapproved"),
                  ("approved", "Listed"),
                  #("Backorder","Backorder"),
                  #("oos","Out of Stock"),
                  #("preorder","Preorder"),
                  ("userdisabled", "User Disabled"),
                  ("disapproved", "Disapproved by admin"),
                  )
```

and the Field:

```
o_status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=PRODUCT_STATUS, verbose_name="Product Status", default="approved")
```

Suppose I wish to limit it to just "approved" and "userdisabled" instead showing the full array (which is what I want to show in the admin), how do I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['your_field'].choices = (('a', 'A'), ('b', 'B'))

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
```

I guess this ain't too different from overriding a queryset from a ForeignKey or M2M attribute.

PS: Thanks peritus from #django at irc.freenode.net